# Issue with finding users not followed by a specific user in Prisma schema

Tags: database, prisma, querying

I am trying to retrieve all the users who are not the current logged in user (the current logged in user is specified by `userId`) and is also not followed by the current logged in user.

This is my database schema,

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mongodb"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model User {
  id             String   @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  username       String   @unique
  imageUrl       String
  externalUserId String   @unique
  bio            String?
  createdAt      DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt      DateTime @updatedAt
  follower       Follow[] @relation("following")
  following      Follow[] @relation("follower")
}

model Follow {
  id          String   @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  followerId  String   @db.ObjectId
  follower    User     @relation("follower", fields: [followerId], references: [id])
  followingId String   @db.ObjectId
  following   User     @relation("following", fields: [followingId], references: [id])
  createdAt   DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt   DateTime @updatedAt

  @@unique([followerId, followingId])
  @@index([followerId])
  @@index([followingId])
}
```

where `follower` relation in the `User` model specifies the list of users who are following a particular user (say A). and `following` relation in the `User` model specifies the list of users who a particular user (A) is following.

I am using the below query to achieve the above mentioned purpose

```
users = await prisma.user.findMany({
  where: {
    AND: [
      {
        NOT: {
          id: userId,
        },
      },
      {
        NOT: {
          follower: {
            some: {
              followerId: userId,
            },
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  orderBy: {
    createdAt: "desc",
  },
});
```

But this query only returns the users who are being followed by the current user (`userId`). I have no clue as to why this is happening. Can anyone please help? What is the right way to do this?